# bpy.ops.nla.bake() bake only x Location

Tags: python, animation

I want to bake my Animation with [`bpy.ops.nla.bake()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.ops.nla.html#bpy.ops.nla.bake), but I only want to bake x Location, because otherwise blender rotates my object and I can't change the Rotation.

Is there a way to set this in the Parameters of bake() function?

Comment: The link to source on [`bpy.ops.nla.bake(...)`](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.ops.nla.html#bpy.ops.nla.bake) is broken.  [anim.py](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/release/scripts/startup/bl_operators/anim.py)  It contains the code to the operator.

Comment: Ok, but I dont't want to change that file. Do you know another way?

Comment: Could use the operator template and paste in the operator code from anim.py.   Edit to suit.